# C++ Boost bind value type

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I look in documentation and source code but cannot figure out how to get return value type of boost bind functor.
I am trying to accomplish following:

```
 35 template<typename T,size_t N, class F>
 36 boost::array<typename F::value_type, N> make_array(T (&input)[N], F unary) {
 37     boost::array<typename F::value_type, N> array;
 38     std::transform(input, input + N, array.begin(), unary);
 39     return array;
 40 }
```

where F can be bind functor.  the above does not work because functor does not have value_type.   for that matter, is there standard interface for unary/binary functor as far as return value.

solution: it should be `result_type`.  also equivalent defined are `argument_type`  and `first/second_argument_type` for binary functions

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh.  nevermind, it's `result_type` rather than `value_type`.

Comment: Not much you can do. Change the title, maybe. Not sure if OP voting to close just counts as just a vote, or if you can vote to close at 3500.